# Swagger is not working with JSONAPI - Golang

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Swagger is not creating example with expected format: How to use swagger with json-api golang

```
Input struct:

type example struct {
    ID           string `jsonapi:"primary,examples"`
    value        string `jsonapi:"attr,value"`
}

Expected format:

{
    "data":[
      {
          "type": "examples",
          "id": "01FDG693F2MS0ZCEW925MZ7BAA",
          "attributes": {
              "value": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
          }
      }
    ],
}
```

Comment: https://jsonapi.org/